# Ошибка при вставке в БД SP2-0552: Bind variable not declared

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, datetime, sqlplus

```sql
insert into trip (id_trip, departure_time, arrival_time, frequency, employee_name, employee_post) 
values (6, 16-05-2020 11:25:00, 16-05-2020 18:42:00, 1, 'Ivanov A. A.', 'Conductor');
```

Тип данных для `arrival_time` - `DATE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не надо полагаться на формат преобразования строковых значений в дату установленный по умолчанию, он может изменится. Одно из двух, либо указывайте его явно:

```sql
SQL> create table trip (id number, departure date);

SQL> insert into trip values (1, to_date ('17-05-2020 13:45:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row inserted.
```

, либо установите желаемый формат в самом начале скрипта:

```sql
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into trip values (1, '16-05-2020 11:25:00');

1 row inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

не хватает кавычек в DateTime.

```
insert into trip (id_trip, departure_time, arrival_time, frequency, employee_name, employee_post) values (6, '16-05-2020 11:25:00', '16-05-2020 18:42:00', 1, 'Ivanov A. A.', 'Conductor');
```